# Could we describe acids and bases using electromagnetism?

Tags: physical-chemistry, classical-electrodynamics

Why don't we use Maxwell's equations in acids and base theory? Surely the interaction between two charged species is readily described by this.

The theory I have so far come across is [HASB theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSAB_theory). This uses the Klopman-salem equation to model both the Coulombic interaction between hard ions and an orbital interaction term between the HOMO-LUMO orbitals. This is the result of quantum perturbation theory.

I suppose quantum tunnelling is inherently un-accouted for in classical electrodynamics, which would constitute a lot of protonation acid-base interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Although they are quite fundamental quantum mechanically (they are the propagation equations for the free photon), Maxwell's equations alone are severely limited. They only describe *free photons*, or with the appropriate constitutive relationships, they can describe the propagation of a quantum superposition of free photons and raised matter states in dielectric and linear magnetic materials. They only works as a model for such superpositions at wavelengths where the photon's field of influence is much larger than the constituent atoms / molecules of materials.

Once you get down to interactions at the scale you are talking of, *i.e.* roughly one thousandfold smaller, you need a great deal more than simply Maxwell's equations, even though they are still there. The electrons both source and are influenced by the electromagnetic field. A lone electron in a potential can be described by the Maxwell-Dirac equations: see for example this paper by the late Hilary Booth of ANU:

[Hilary Booth, "ELECTRONS WITH SELF-FIELD AS SOLUTIONS TO NONLINEAR PDE", **39**  *Proceedings of the Centre for Mathematics and its Applications (Australian National University)*](http://maths-proceedings.anu.edu.au/039/CMAproc39-booth.pdf)

I am not expert in this area: the Klopman equation you cite *looks* to me as like the kind of thing that one gets from time dependent perturbation (expansion of a system's quantum states as a series of eigenstates of nonperturbed system) on a simple model that probably resembles something like the above, although it will be a multiparticle quantum system (the chemically interacting species). What I mean by this is that it is typical of such things: **I have not gone into the details of this theory, which is not wonted to me**. Maxwell's equations are of course showing up there as you already understand as the Coulombic interaction terms. But there is a good deal else as well!

Answer (score 1):

HSAB is an empirical classification of chemical species on the basis of mutual reactivity or inertness towards each other - it is not a theory in the sense of fundamental framework. Klopman-Salem equation is *post facto* rationalisation in terms of one-electron wavefunctions, the results of which are inherently dependent on chosen atomic basis, and/or any post Hartree-Fock method used to calculate the ground state. Usefulness of such approach lies not in its theoretical strength, but in employing these in close conjunction with experimental results. Without extensive benchmarking, agreement of methods like Klopman-Salem with experiment is random at best.

Comment: Other aspect is: The tunneling effects in acid-base reactions primarily refer to proton tunneling along acid-base reaction coordinate. It is not possible to capture these with semi-classical reaction dynamics based on internuclear potential derived from adiabatic (Born-Oppenheimer)ground electronic state utlised in Klopman-Salem equation.